# Upgrading from WebDriver 2.53.1 to 3.5.2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have a testsuite which uses `WebDriver` 2.53.1 and now I try it to upgrade to 3.5.2.
I added the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", C:\\Portable\\firefox.exe);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to(url);
```

When I execute test, I see the following:

> 1503575087525 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
>   1503575087525 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:20041
>   1503575088303 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser
>   C:/Portable/firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]

I get this JSON output on the given port:

```
{"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"GET / did not match a known command","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x4bb74f - <no info>\n   1:           0x4bbea9 - <no info>\n   2:           0x43ce8d - <no info>\n   3:           0x4319fd - <no info>\n   4:           0x425ca5 - <no info>\n   5:           0x407eba - <no info>\n   6:           0x6d95b9 - <no info>\n   7:           0x417655 - <no info>\n   8:           0x6d38b3 - <no info>\n   9:     0x7ffdddfa13d2 - BaseThreadInitThunk"}}
```

It opens welcome page in browser and doesn't go to given URL.

Comment: you need to upgarde your firefox as well

Comment: @ShubhamJain : I use a pretty new version, 54.0.

Comment: Are you upgrading to 3.5.1 or 3.5.2? The title and description are contradicting themselves.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens: I upgrade from 2.53.1 to 3.5.2.